# Is there Data Loader for QGIS or Spatialite?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatialite, file-geodatabase, field-mapping

Is there a tool that works like the data loader of ArcGIS for QGIS (or via Spatialite )?
To integrate data in a database or a shapefile without having the same structure (and the tool allows to propose which column goes with every other column)

For example, we have a layer of trees; two people go on the field and inform each new tree layer (without necessarily having the same structure / field names).
They come back ; I want to integrate their new trees quickly and easily without having to explicitly rename their fields: ArcGIS allows in a geodatabase with the tool "load data" that makes a direct link between the fields of the two layers (linking with a gui).

Comment: Could you maybe go deeper into detail with an example maybe if possible. I'm not familar with that and never did anything but maybe that would help. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found anything like that yet, lets hope that there is one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with spatialite, here's how to do what you want:
The SQL format is

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT FROM ...
```

So, suppose you have a permanent spatial table "trees" with columns attrib1, attrib2, attrib3. Now one of the field guys brings a new shapefile "new_trees" with equivalent fields col_x, col_y, col_z. You would import the new shapefile into spatialite then do:

```
INSERT INTO trees (attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, geometry)
SELECT col_x, col_y, col_z, geometry FROM new_trees;
```

And then you can drop the imported "new_trees" table